Is there alternative way of expressing .s files in gcc?
I realize this may get rejected by Stack Overflow, but:
I use a compiler that generates .s files to be assembled by gcc. I mix in C files as well, so the final gcc command line contains a mix of .s and .c files. Because .s files are just an intermediate file to me, I want to erase all of them in a make clean. Thus the problem. There are .s files, assembly files, that contain hand written code and other .s files that are generated. It would be an ideal solution if (say), .asm were a proper alternative to .s files, that way I could have the assembly files I want to keep as .asm files, and .s files are junk that can be removed. Is there another alternative to .s files? (the extension)?
A search turned up .S and .sx extensions, but each of those has special meanings. I (ideally) want a proper alias to .s files.
I actually tried .asm as an extension, I got:

$ gcc test.asm -o test
/usr/bin/ld:test.asm: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:test.asm:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


From Mike below I got:

gcc test1.c -x assembler test.asm -o test

Which works, and allows mixed C and assembly source.

The easiest solution is probably to use the .S file extension and ignore that the C preprocessor is run.

I considered that, the issue for me is that is putting a time bomb in the code. A year from now someone finds out that the preprocessor is causing issues. Besides, its an unused and unnecessary extra pass. The solution from Mike below is better, but thanks.

I strongly recommend to separate source and build directories from each other.

Usually, instead of passing all the source files on the command line at once, you would compile them one by one into object files, and then link all the object files.  So instead of gcc foo1.c foo2.c bar.s -o foo you would have four separate commands: gcc -c foo1.c ; gcc -c foo2.c ; gcc -c bar.s ; gcc foo1.o foo2.o bar.o -o foo.  This is easy to automate with make or similar.  It has the advantage that when one source file changes, you don't need to recompile any of the others, which speeds up the development cycle.

And it avoids the issue of your command line being sensitive to the ordering of the -x options, since you can just use gcc -x assembler -c bar.asm to assemble those specific files, and keep everything else the same.  It also means that you can use different options when compiling C than when assembling.

Yes, you can keep the assembly files as e.g. file.asm and
just tell gcc to treat them as assembly source:
gcc -c -x assembler -o file.o file.asm

Or tell your build system to tell gcc to do that.
See the GCC Manual, 3.2 Options Controlling the Kind of Output:
-x language
Specify explicitly the language for the following input files 
(rather than letting the compiler choose a default based on the 
file name suffix). This option applies to all following input files 
until the next -x option. Possible values for language are:

    c  c-header  cpp-output
    c++  c++-header  c++-system-header c++-user-header c++-cpp-output
    objective-c  objective-c-header  objective-c-cpp-output
    objective-c++ objective-c++-header objective-c++-cpp-output
    assembler  assembler-with-cpp
    ada
    d
    f77  f77-cpp-input f95  f95-cpp-input
    go

You would want -x assembler-with-cpp if your assembly sources contain pre-processing directives.
And if you want to turn off -x <lang> further down the commandline and resume business as usual:
-x none
Turn off any specification of a language, so that subsequent 
files are handled according to their file name suffixes 
(as they are if -x has not been used at all).


Alright, so gcc test1.c -x assembler test.asm -o test works, so -x assembler treats all files AFTER that option as assembly. I presume that means there is another option to turn the mode to assume C files back on. I'll look it up! Thanks.
